# How to conditional format if a cell is within 10 of another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i'm trying to make a formula that colors a cell if the price is within $10 or more of the high and within $10 or more of the low

This is the formula I used for the high

`=A2>=D2-10`

and this for the low

`=A2<=G2+10`

For some reason its colors the true and false for both formulas

[image: Example pic]

Link to example [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cw2Ym6OOQX62Qo741aGCZ-yTpqNB97cBY1x684KNlJU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas are fine, but need to be applied to D2:D1000 and G2:G1000.

You might want to check that A is not blank though:

```
=and(A2>=D2-10,A2<>"")
```

[image]

similarly with the formula for G:

```
=and(A2<=G2+10,A2<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for checking for blank tip, what a silly mistake. Why doesn't the formula work if you set the range as the whole column? Thank you for your time

Comment: If you set the range to D1:D1000, starting from D1, it will apply the formula which compares A2 to D2. Then in D2, the formula will be adjusted automatically so it will compare A3 to D3. If you look at your original results, the formatting always gives the correct result for the row below, not the current row.

Comment: I see now Thank you